# stack level to deep Rails 2.3.14

Tags: ruby-on-rails, redmine, redmine-plugins

I'm developing a plugin for a management framework and when I start the webrick server in the development mode, a strange error raises(stack level too deep). It happens when an action (e.g. the `show` action) starts to render a template. Unfortunately i have no idea why this is happen.

```
SystemStackError in Stories#show

Showing vendor/plugins/stories/app/views/stories/show.rhtml where line #5 raised:

stack level too deep

Extracted source (around line #5):

    5: link_to_if_authorized 'aa', {:controller => "stories", :action => "index", :id => @story.id, :project_id => @story.project.id}, :title => l(:view_story), :class => 'icon icon-zoom-out'
    6: link_to_if_authorized 'bb', {:controller => "stories", :action => "edit", :id => @story.id, :project_id => @story.project.id}, :title => l(:button_edit), :class => 'icon icon-edit'
    7: link_to 'bb', {:id => @story.id, :project_id => @story.project.id}, :confirm => 'Really  delete?', :method => :delete, :class => 'icon icon-del' if User.current.allowed_to? (:delete_stories, @project)

    RAILS_ROOT: /home/haendwic/Documents/Aptana Studio 3 Workspace/1.4-stable-SVN
    Application Trace | Framework Trace | Full Trace

    /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.3.14/lib/active_record/attribute_methods.rb:248:in method_missing'
    /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.3.14/lib/active_record/attribute_methods.rb:249:in method_missing'
     /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.3.14/lib/active_record/associations /association_proxy.rb:215:in send'
     /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.3.14/lib/active_record/associations/association_proxy.rb:215:in method_missing'
     /home/haendwic/Documents/Aptana Studio 3 Workspace/1.4-stable-SVN/vendor/plugins/stories/app/views/stories/show.rhtml:5:in  _run_rhtml_vendor47plugins47stories47app47views47stories47show46rhtml'
     /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.3.14/lib/action_view/renderable.rb:34:in send'
      /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.3.14/lib/action_view/renderable.rb:34:in render'
      /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.3.14/lib/action_view/base.rb:306:in with_template'
      /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.3.14/lib/action_view/renderable.rb:30:in render'
      /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.3.14/lib/action_view/template.rb:205:in render_template'
     /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.3.14/lib/action_view/base.rb:265:in render'
     /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.3.14/lib/action_view/base.rb:348:in _render_with_layout'
     /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.3.14/lib/action_view/base.rb:262:in render'
     /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.3.14/lib/action_controller/base.rb:1252:in render_for_file'
     /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.3.14/lib/action_controller/base.rb:936:in render_without_benchmark'
    /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.3.14/lib/action_controller/benchmarking.rb:51:in render'
    /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.14/lib/active_support/core_ext/benchmark.rb:17:in ms'
    /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/benchmark.rb:308:in realtime'
    /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.14/lib/active_support/core_ext/benchmark.rb:17:in ms'
    /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.3.14/lib/action_controller/benchmarking.rb:51:in render'
/home/haendwic/Documents/Aptana Studio 3 Workspace/1.4-stable-SVN/vendor/plugins/stories/app/controllers/stories_controller.rb:104:in show'
     /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.3.14/lib/action_controller/mime_responds.rb:135:in call'
      /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.3.14/lib/action_controller/mime_responds.rb:135:in custom'
     /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.3.14/lib/action_controller/mime_responds.rb:179:in call'
     /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.3.14/lib/action_controller/mime_responds.rb:179:in respond'
     /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.3.14/lib/action_controller/mime_responds.rb:173:in each'
     /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.3.14/lib/action_controller/mime_responds.rb:173:in respond'
      /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.3.14/lib/action_controller/mime_responds.rb:107:in respond_to'
    /home/haendwic/Documents/Aptana Studio 3 Workspace/1.4-stable-SVN/vendor/plugins/stories/app/controllers/stories_controller.rb:102:in show'
     /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.3.14/lib/action_controller/base.rb:1333:in send'
     /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.3.14/lib/action_controller/base.rb:1333:in perform_action_without_filters'
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.3.14/lib/action_controller/filters.rb:617:in call_filters'
     /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.3.14/lib/action_controller/filters.rb:610:in perform_action_without_benchmark'
     /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.3.14/lib/action_controller/benchmarking.rb:68:in perform_action_without_rescue'
     /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.14/lib/active_support/core_ext/benchmark.rb:17:in ms'
     /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/benchmark.rb:308:in realtime'
     /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.14/lib/active_support/core_ext/benchmark.rb:17:in ms'
     /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.3.14/lib/action_controller/benchmarking.rb:68:in perform_action_without_rescue'
     /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.3.14/lib/action_controller/rescue.rb:160:in perform_action_without_flash'
     /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.3.14/lib/action_controller/flash.rb:151:in perform_action'
     /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.3.14/lib/action_controller/base.rb:532:in send'
     /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.3.14/lib/action_controller/base.rb:532:in process_without_filters'
     /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.3.14/lib/action_controller/filters.rb:606:in process'
     /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.3.14/lib/action_controller/base.rb:391:in process'
     /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.3.14/lib/action_controller/base.rb:386:in call'
     /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.3.14/lib/action_controller/routing/route_set.rb:438:in call'
     /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.3.14/lib/action_controller/dispatcher.rb:87:in dispatch'
    /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.3.14/lib/action_controller/dispatcher.rb:121:in _call'
    /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.3.14/lib/action_controller/dispatcher.rb:130:in build_middleware_stack'
    /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.3.14/lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:29:in call'
    /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.3.14/lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:29:in call'
    /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.3.14/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/query_cache.rb:34:in cache'
     /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.3.14/lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:9:in cache'
     /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.3.14/lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:28:in call'
     /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.3.14/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:361:in call'
    /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.3.14/lib/action_controller/string_coercion.rb:25:in call'
    /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/rack-1.1.3/lib/rack/head.rb:9:in call'
    /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/rack-1.1.3/lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:24:in call'
    /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.3.14/lib/action_controller/params_parser.rb:15:in call'
    /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.3.14/lib/action_controller/session /cookie_store.rb:99:in call'
    /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.3.14/lib/action_controller/failsafe.rb:26:in call'
    /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/rack-1.1.3/lib/rack/lock.rb:11:in call'
    /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/rack-1.1.3/lib/rack/lock.rb:11:in synchronize'
    /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/rack-1.1.3/lib/rack/lock.rb:11:in call'
    /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.3.14/lib/action_controller/dispatcher.rb:114:in call'
    /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.3.14/lib/action_controller/reloader.rb:34:in run'
    /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.3.14/lib/action_controller/dispatcher.rb:108:in call'
    /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/rails-2.3.14/lib/rails/rack/static.rb:31:in call'
    /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/rack-1.1.3/lib/rack/urlmap.rb:47:in call'
    /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/rack-1.1.3/lib/rack/urlmap.rb:41:in each'
    /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/rack-1.1.3/lib/rack/urlmap.rb:41:in call'
    /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/rails-2.3.14/lib/rails/rack/log_tailer.rb:17:in call'
    /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/rack-1.1.3/lib/rack/content_length.rb:13:in call'
    /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/rack-1.1.3/lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:48:in service'
    /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/httpserver.rb:104:in service'
    /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/httpserver.rb:65:in run'
    /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/server.rb:173:in start_thread'
    /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/server.rb:162:in start'
    /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/server.rb:162:in start_thread'
    /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/server.rb:95:in start'
    /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/server.rb:92:in each'
    /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/server.rb:92:in start'
    /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/server.rb:23:in start'
    /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/server.rb:82:in start'
    /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/rack-1.1.3/lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:14:in run'
    /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/rails-2.3.14/lib/commands/server.rb:111
    script/server:3:in require'
    script/server:3
Request

Parameters:

{"project_id"=>"1",
 "id"=>"2"}

Show session dump
Response

Headers:

{"Cache-Control"=>"no-cache",
 "Content-Type"=>"text/html"}
```

and here is the action from the controller

```
def show 
 @edit_allowed = User.current.allowed_to?(:edit_stories, @project)
 respond_to do |format|
  format.html {
    render :template => 'stories/show'
  }
  format.api
  format.pdf  { send_data(story_to_pdf(@story), :type => 'application/pdf', :filename => "#{@project.identifier}-#{@story.id}.pdf") }
 end                                
end
```

and at last a part of the view

```
     link_to_if_authorized 'aa', {:controller => "stories", :action => "index", :id => @story.id, :project_id => @story.project.id}, :title => l(:view_story), :class => 'icon icon-zoom-out'
     link_to_if_authorized 'bb', {:controller => "stories", :action => "edit", :id => @story.id, :project_id => @story.project.id}, :title => l(:button_edit), :class => 'icon icon-edit' 
    link_to 'bb', {:id => @story.id, :project_id => @story.project.id}, :confirm => 'Really delete?', :method => :delete, :class => 'icon icon-del' if User.current.allowed_to?(:delete_stories, @project)
```

Maybe it's important to say, that in the production mode the plugin is stable and routes the actions (incl. show) correctly

Comment: Can you post the code for `link_to_if_authorized`?

Comment: Do you have you the same version of ruby in production and development?

Comment: def link_to_if_authorized(name, options = {}, html_options = nil, *parameters_for_method_reference)
    link_to(name, options, html_options, *parameters_for_method_reference) if authorize_for(options[:controller] || params[:controller], options[:action])
  end

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is typically caused by you (or others) patching core models (probably the `Project` model) from a plugin without taking the rails reloader into account.

If you override methods (e.g. using `alias_method_chain`) and your patch is loaded twice, you can easily create an infinite loop when calling the old method.

```
# This is our initial class
class MyClass
  def foo
    puts "original foo"
  end
end

module Patch
  def self.included(base)
    base.alias_method_chain :foo, :feature
  end

  def foo_with_feature
    foo_without_feature # call the "original" method
    puts "foo with feature"
  end
end

# patch the class
MyClass.send(:include, Patch)

# Now call the patched method
MyClass.new.foo
# prints:
#   original foo
#   foo with feature
```

`foo` now refers to the method `foo_with_feature` while the original `foo` method now is accessible from `foo_without_feature`

All right, until now everything looked good. Now let's see what happens, if we load our patch again

```
# patch again
MyClass.send(:include, Patch)

# And call the method again
MyClass.new.foo
# SystemStackError: stack level too deep
#   from (irb):7:in `foo_without_feature'
#   from (irb):7:in `foo'
#   from (irb):27
```

You see a SystemStackError caused by an infinite loop. This is because after the second loading of the patch, `foo_without_feature` now refers to the `foo_with_feature` method from the first patch. When calling it, it will over and over again call `foo_without_feature` until the stack is full.

You said that it only crashes on the second request. This is exactly the typical behavior when something is odd on the class reloader. By default, Rails will reload all classes on every request in development mode but only once in production mode.

Taming the rails reloader is a bit tricky sometimes. As some general guidelines, you should

1. use `require_dependency` instead of `require` when loading patches
2. load your patches using [`Dispatcher.to_prepare`](http://theadmin.org/articles/how-to-modify-core-redmine-classes-from-a-plugin/)
3. always declare the patched classes `unloadable`

The most critical part is using `Dispatcher.to_prepare`. It is a callback which is called once in production mode and before each request in development mode and is thus the ideal place for loading patches.

As a side note though: When using Redmine 2 (or the upcoming ChiliProject 4), i.e. Rails 3, the class patching will be rather different from this approach - most probably easier.

Comment: Thanks man, it seems to work. I needed to add some require_dependences to 2 controllers and the error seems to be fixed..

Answer (score 0):

The "stack level too deep" error means that you have a stack overflow (it happens often enough to have a site named after it). That occurs when a function calls itself indefinitely or when two functions call each other indefinitely.

Your error happens on line 5, so I'd check the source for `link_to_if_authorized`. Something in there is causing an infinite loop.

Comment: def link_to(name, options={})
        url = { :format => name.to_s.downcase }.merge(options.delete(:url) || {}).except('page')
        caption = options.delete(:caption) || name
        html_options = { :class => name.to_s.downcase, :rel => 'nofollow' }.merge(options)
        @view.content_tag('span', @view.link_to(caption, url, html_options))
      end

Comment: def link_to_if_authorized(name, options = {}, html_options = nil, *parameters_for_method_reference) link_to(name, options, html_options, *parameters_for_method_reference) if authorize_for(options[:controller] || params[:controller], options[:action])

Comment: when i comment out both methods (link_to, link_to_if_authorized), the same error raises, so the problem must be start earlier(?)

Comment: and if i restart the server, the first request works fine. after this, the stack level horror begins..