# redmine:migrate_from_trac -stack level too deep error

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, redmine, trac

After successful installation of redmine , trying to migrate the datas from trac to redmine . i am getting the following error.... . Any work around to fix this

```
 user@user:~/redmine-2.3$ rake redmine:migrate_from_trac RAILS_ENV="production"

    WARNING: a new project will be added to Redmine during this process.
    Are you sure you want to continue ? [y/N] y

    Trac directory []: /home/user/implementation Trac database adapter (sqlite3, mysql2, postgresql) [sqlite3]: 
    Trac database encoding [UTF-8]: 
    Target project identifier []: implementation

    Migrating components.......................................................................................................................................................................................
    Migrating milestones.......................................
    Migrating custom fields...
    Migrating tickets..................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................
    Migrating wiki.....

    Components:      178/183
    Milestones:      39/39
    Tickets:         2082/2082
    Ticket files:    0/421
    Custom values:   2812/2812
    Wiki edits:      5/5
    Wiki files:      0/0
    rake aborted!
    stack level too deep

    Tasks: TOP => redmine:migrate_from_trac
    (See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

Comment: This question might have some relevant information on the issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11283255

Answer (score 0):

This is a typical stack overflow error, means a function is recursively called in an infinite loop. That is caused by a bug in that script, likely because your data is somehow corrupted and the script is not able to stand that.

Try to call the script with the `--verbose` flag, or check the log files for error messages. Try to find the error in your data by running the script testwise with reduced data input (e.g. without tickets).

Comment: or simply keep the Trac system